# Cosign Digital Signature Appliance SAPI Local

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to develop a C++ application for signing pdf using the SAPI Local of Cosign Digital Signature Appliance, running at web server. Our DSA is used in Common Criteria EAL4+, meaning that  user is prompted for his OTP whenever he signs.
Can anyone give me guidelines for the credential parameter of SAPISignatureFieldCreateSignEx function. Unfortunately the related manual does not give any information about this parameter and the HelloWorld example at github is not for Common Criteria EAL4+.
Thanks in advance!
Best Regards,
Anna

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the start of the guide: "Any digital signature operation must be authorized by presenting the user’s password and an OTP displayed by the user’s OTP device.
This means that any digital signature interface that is used must also be provided with an extended authentication parameter that includes both the static password of the user and a One Time Password (OTP)."
So, you need to concatenate the static password and the OTP and provide the concatenation as the password for the SAPISignatureFieldCreateSignEx function in the Crediential and CredentialLen parameters.
Thank you